# How do i display the longest array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to create a Javascript array of words, then use Javascript to find the longest word and print it to the screen. Here is my code:

```
var StrValues = []
StrValues[0] = ["cricket"]
StrValues[1] = ["basketball"]
StrValues[2] = ["hockey"]
StrValues[3] = ["swimming"]
StrValues[4] = ["soccer"]
StrValues[5] = ["tennis"]

document.writeln(StrValues);
```

Comment: Firstly, you're redefining StrValues, correct that.

Comment: Longest array or longest word ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` to find the longest string in a array. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2sebnb33/1/

```
for(var i=0;i<StrValues .length;i++){
    if(StrValues [i].length>len){
        len=StrValues [i].length;index=i;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to correct the way you are creating array.

For instance, it should be like this

```
var StrValues = [];
StrValues[0] = ["cricket"];
```

The logic

```
var longestWord = "";

for (var i = 0 ; i < StrValues.length; i++) {
   if(StrValues[i].length > longestWord.length) {
       longestWord = StrValues[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var strValues = ["cricket", "basketball", "hockey"];
var max = '';
for(var i = 0; i< strValues.length; i++) {
   max = strValues[i].length > max.length ? strValues[i] : max;
}

alert(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```js
var array = [];
array.push("cat");
array.push("children");
array.push("house");
array.push("table");
array.push("amazing");

var maxSize = 0;
var maxSizeWord = "";

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (maxSize < array[i].length) {
    maxSize = array[i].length;
    maxSizeWord = array[i];
  }
}

alert("The biggest word is '" + maxSizeWord + "' with length '" + maxSize + "'!");
```